# Bold text in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I want to have buttons for html tags and highlighting the text, i start with 
 tag:

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        SimpleAttributeSet sas = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setBold(sas, true);
        insertText(getCaretPosition(), "<br>");
        helpTextPane.getStyledDocument().setCharacterAttributes(getInputTextLenght() - 4, getInputTextLenght(), sas, false);
        StyleConstants.setBold(sas, false);
    }
```

the output is as follows: [image] and i totally do not know why every second time the text inside the br tag is bold :/ I want to have only html br tag bold, no the text inside the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StyledDocument's method

```
public void setCharacterAttributes(int offset, int length, AttributeSet s, boolean replace)
```

The second param should be length

So try

```
setCharacterAttributes(getInputTextLenght() - 4, 4, sas, false);
```

Comment: you are right, i try also with 4 before i wrote the question but the result is the same..:/

Comment: Mea Culpa, the problem was that I have created two different AtributeSet, that is why problems appears..